# How do I prevent spam in a vBulletin forum?

Tags: vbulletin

I'm using vBulletin 4.0.8 and I'm receiving spams every day. I used reCaptcha method to avoid spamming but the problem still persists. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Akismet and also you can read [this](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1003722) post.

Answer (score 0):

other mod you can use with online database
[[GlowHost] Spam-O-Matic - Spam Firewall stops forum spam](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=248042)

How it Works
This data responsible for blocking user registrations comes from the stopforumspam.com (SFS) spammer database. After the user who is trying to register passes the built-in vBulletin registration checks which you have configured in your vBulletin settings, SOM then checks the SFS database to see if the IP, username, or email address that the user is trying to register with has been recently tagged as a known spam source on other forums around the Internet. Also can be configured to check the Akismet service for known comment spam.

and other Features:
StopForumSpam
Auto-Moderation
Akismet Service
Newbies Manager

you need get api code from akismet.com and add to product settings

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters.  I believe that this link is a useful and a good answer to this question.  However, link only answers are discouraged and others often down vote them.  Please try to provide more than a link in your answers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for comment i try to add more describe

Answer (score 0):

There is a forum thread on the [vBulletin website about this.  It include the following tips](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-3-8/vbulletin-3-8-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/vbulletin-quick-tips-and-customizations/216851-how-to-reduce-spam-and-registration-bots):

1. Moderate new registrations.
2. Activate email verification.
3. Enable image verification.
4. Ban 'free' email domains many spammers use
5. Disable "Can Use Email to Friend" and "Can Email Members" for new users
6. Add an extra question to the registration to prevent bot registrations.
7. Use a verification image on "contact us"